# Any function in $L^p$ space is a linear combination of simple functions? True OR not?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, approximation, lp-spaces

**Any function in $L^p$ space is a linear combination of simple functions for $1<p<\infty$.**

Is this true?

So any function in $L^p$ is measurable.

So any measurable function can be represented as a linear combination of simple functions.

So I think the statement should be true.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, your understanding is not correct. All simple functions are measurable, but in most $\sigma$-algebras of interest, far more functions are also measurable. For instance, all continuous functions are measurable for the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, but only constant continuous functions are simple.

What is true is that all measurable functions can be realized as a.e. limits of sequences of simple functions.

Comment: oh, ok then simple functions are dense in $L_p$, but it's not that every function in $L_p$ is simple. is this right?

Comment: @user232063 Yes that's right.